# Set intersection that considers values within a certain range as intersecting

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, range, set-intersection

I'm trying to compute the intersection of 2 sets in Python and I'd like to consider values that are within a certain range (+/- 5) as being equal. So for example:

```
set1 = [22, 570, 233, 127, 92]

set2 = [897, 27, 673, 231, 45]
```

What I want is for:

```
len[x for x in set1 if x in set2] == 2
```

where the intersections are 22 & 27 as well as 233 & 231.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You are using list notation. Are you working with "real" sets or lists? I think this can be done efficiently after sorting the sets/lists.

Comment: I want 'len[x for x in set1 if x in set2] ' to be equal to 2, counting 22 & 27 as an intersection and 233 & 231 as an intersection.

Answer (score 1):

If by "efficient" you mean "short", sure.

```
>>> set1 = [22, 570, 233, 127, 92]
>>> set2 = [897, 27, 673, 231, 45]
>>> len([x for x in set1 if any(abs(x-y) <= 5 for y in set2)])
2
```

If by "efficient" you mean "with a reasonable big-O run time", that's not so easy. The above approach is O(N^2). You could get O(N * log(N)) if you sort both sets and iterate over them in parallel looking for approximate matches, but it's not entirely trivial to do.

[edit - removed O(N log N) code that worked for the OP's input but not for set1=[1,3,4] and set2=[2,10]]

Comment: upvoted. In case the OP wants to keep the values from both sets do `[(e1,e2) for e1 in set1 for e2 in set2 if abs(e1-e2) <= delta]`

Answer (score 0):

At the expense of memory, for smallish ranges (your example said +-5), you could just make larger `set`s for the check.

```
from itertools import chain

set1 = {22, 570, 233, 127, 92}
set2 = {897, 27, 673, 231, 45}

# Make a frozenset of all values considered overlapping with set2
overlap = 5
overlaprange = range(-overlap, overlap+1)
match2 = frozenset(chain.from_iterable((x + i for i in overlaprange) for x in set2))

print(len(set1 & match2))
```

This will never count a single element more than once, and if the values in `set2` are close together, doesn't store their overlap more than once (conversion to `frozenset` for `match2` uniquifies). If one of the `set`s is being matched against several other `set`s, you'd convert the reused `set` to a "match `set`", then use that over and over for each intersection check.